# Validation in setter is not called in the constructor of a constructor function

Tags: javascript

Having the following constructor function:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'lastName', {
        get() {
            return lastName;
        },

        set(value) {
            if (!value) {
                throw new Error('Last name is required');
            }

            lastName = value;
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'fullName', {
        get() {
            return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
        }
    });
}
```

Here I expect the error is invoked because I omit in the constructor the value for the lastName property

```
try {
    let person = new Person('john');

    console.log(person.fullName);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(`ValidationError: ${error.message}`);
}
```

But instead I am getting the output `john undefined`

The only way the error is invoked is if I explicitly called the property from the object.

```
try {
    let person = new Person();

    person.firstName = 'john';
    person.lastName = '';

    console.log(person.fullName);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(`ValidationError: ${error.message}`);
}
```

Here I am getting the expected message `ValidationError: Last name is required`.

What is the correct way for the validation to be executed when set in the constructor?

Comment: A hint: your code currently creates a `lastName` field and sets it to `undefined`, then overwrites that field with a property named `lastName`.

Comment: You may need to set `writable: true` in `defineProperty` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: I am probably misinterpreting this but I understand that the set method of the lastName property will be invoked when assigning a value in the constructor and consequently the validation will be verified and the same applies if the value assigned to lastName property is mutated in the object

Answer (score 0):

You define the `lastName` getter / setter pair *after* you set the property in the constructor. To get it work *first* define the property, than set it. Or you just do:

```
 function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    if(!lastName) throw new Error("lastName is required");

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering, but in my case this is just one of the validations and I would like to keep them on the setter